# How to use one Android phone as a handsfree device to another (via Bluetooth)?

Tags: applications, bluetooth, hands-free

I have an extra Android device (a mobile phone, Samsung Galaxy Y Duos, S6102B, Android 2.3.6 - rooted), that I call D1 here, and would like to use it as my "car brain", like a low-cost multimedia central, to do a lot of things.

On this question, I would like to know:

- If I have another Android device, called here D2;
- How to play every sound from D2 on D1 using bluetooth connection.

Example:

1. I'm on a call on D2. When I enter the car and turn D1 on, when D1 and D2 become bluetooth-paired, I can drive and continue talking via D1 (like a handsfree device), with D2 on my pocket;
2. I'm hearing music on D2 with my headphones. When I enter the car and turn D1 on, when D1 and D2 become bluetooth-paired, I can hear the music from D2.

Comment: Ok for BT question: it is impossible for a lot of Android devices. But how about the wi-fi solution?? I'll edit it here to be only a BT question and I'll open a wi-fi question :/